# Stacked <div> elements with bottom border of upper <div> creating a separation

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have my page look like the image below.  I want the top portion(white) to fill 75% of the page height while the remaining space is filled by green.  I thought of using a bottom border(gray) of the upper  to create a separation.  The problem I have is that the bottom border does not show up.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

[image: Desired look]

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.top,
.bottom {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.top {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #C4C2C2;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  top: 0;
  height: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: #66BC29;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25%;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
</div>
<div class="bottom">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The bottom border is covered by the bottom div.  Add a z-index to your top style:

```
.top { 
    ...
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLx0ob7c/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `.bottom { border-top: 5px solid #ccc; }` this will work

Comment: try to apply with border-top instead border-bottom

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: fixed` from `.top, .bottom { }` and your border will render correctly, though this does create other issues that will need to be resolved by removing the `margin` and `padding` that the `<body>` element has by default.

Answer (score 0):

`border-bottom` is overlaping with bottom div so removed this and used 
`border-top` to bottom div to give you same result. Thanks

```css
body {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .top,
    .bottom {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .top { 
        background-color: #FFFFFF; 
        top: 0;
        height: 75%;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .bottom { 
        background-color: #66BC29;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 25%;
        padding-right: 35px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        border-top:4px solid #C4C2C2;
    }
```

```html
<div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
    </div>
```